# Remove free shipping method after apply coupon code

Tags: magento

How to remove free shipping method after apply coupon code in cart page as well as onepagecheckout page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup price rules for coupon codes in **Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules**

Set the conditions for the coupons that they only work if **Shipping Method  is not  [freeshipping] Free**

This will not hide the option of the free shipping, but the coupon code will not work when selecting the free shipping option (it removes the coupon code when selection it.).

If you want to remove the option completly from one page checkout, you will need to code it. (i dont know any other way)
something like this should work:

```
<?php
$coupon = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
if(!$coupon) {

FREE SHIPPING CODE FROM ONEPAGECHECKOUT IN HERE, IF NO COUPON CODE FOUND.

}
?>
```

Comment: I have did this code in /app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php. in collect function. but i want also that if i have applied coupon code and there is a grand total more then 30$ then freeshipping should be work. but when i print grand total in Freeshipping.php file it prints zero.. is there something like grand_total in config.xml have to use?

Comment: if you code it in the files located in /app/design/frontend/default/THEME , then it should work much better. Cant say what file, because i do not know. You can write php in the phtml files

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this using the following approach, so posting in case anyone else is looking. Copy the following file:

*/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php*

to your local folder, creating the directories, so you have:

*/app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php*

Then replace lines 70 to 86, which are like this:

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
        || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
            $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
    ) {
        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $method->setPrice('0.00');
        $method->setCost('0.00');

        $result->append($method);
    }
```

...with the following:

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
        || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
            $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
    ) {
        $coupon = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
        $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
        if(isset($totals['discount'])) {
            $discount = abs($totals['discount']->getValue()); // Discount value if applied
        } else {
            $discount = '';
        }
        // No free shipping if coupon used, unless GRAND total is still over free-shipping limit
        if(!$coupon || $coupon && ($totals['subtotal']->getValue() - $discount) > $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal')) {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice('0.00');
            $method->setCost('0.00');

            $result->append($method);
        }
    }
```

Now, if a coupon code gets used, Magento checks whether the GRAND total is still above the free shipping threshold before applying it.